# Parse an item depending on previous elements

Tags: python, parsing, kaitai-struct

To give some context, I am parsing a DICOM file, and having difficulties using the Transfer Syntax entry to determine whether to use implicit or explicit parsing. But let me define a simplified syntax, so no dicom knowledge is required.

We have a sequence of entries, each entry has a `group number` , and a `data` part. The group number is always represented as `u2`, but the data can be of different types, lets say `u2` or `u4`. The order of the entries can be arbitrary, except that all the entries with `group number == 2` must be at the top. All entries with `group number == 2` has a data type of `u2`, but subsequent data parts can differ.

And here comes the hard part: all the items with `group number != 2` have data type `u4` if and only if an entry exactly like this was present previously:

```
(group, data) == (0x0002, 0x0101)
```

In python for example, I would parse it like this:

```
def read_entries(stream):
  is_u4 = False
  while not stream.eos():
    group = stream.read_u2()
    if group != 2 and is_u4:
      data = stream.read_u4()
    else:      
      data = stream.read_u2()
    if group == 2 and data == 0x0101:
      is_u4 = True
    yield (group, data)
```

Is there a way to achieve this using kaitai-struct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Short answer

Exact transcription of Python code to KS per se is impossible right now, only by [plugging in the code](http://doc.kaitai.io/user_guide.html#_opaque_types_plugging_in_external_code) written in imperative language.

However, thanks to your additional info, an alternative approach is available, see below for solution.

#### Longer answer

Kaitai Struct emphasizes stateless parsing, thus everything we parse is effectively immutable (read-only), i.e. there are variables that can change its value during the parsing. Thus propagating `is_u4` between parse cycles is non-trivial thing to do. We have similar problem with [MIDI running status](https://github.com/kaitai-io/kaitai_struct/issues/39), for example.

Some of the solutions suggested by people sometimes is recursive type definition + propagation of instances using `_parent` syntax (see [issue #70](https://github.com/kaitai-io/kaitai_struct_compiler/issues/70)), but:

- This is currently hindered by lack of type definition for recursively defined instance values + lack of initial value seeding
- This generates a linked list of values, not an array (i.e. that's not what most people are comfortable with)
- This takes heavy toll on call stack (i.e. monstrously long structures would most likely fail with stack exhaustion)

Alternative approach, given additional information you've provided might be viable. Actually, it turns out that whole stream of elements can be grouped in 3 groups:

- elements before (0x0002, 0x0101) - they all use u2-u2 format
- the (0x0002, 0x0101) element itself - note that it is also always u2-u2 when it's encountered for the first time
- elements after (0x0002, 0x0101) - they all use u2-u4 format; even if additional (0x0002, 0x0101) are encountered afterwards, per the algorithm you've provided, it should be read as u2-u4, so it's ok.

Thus it possible to get away with:

```
types:
  elements:
    seq:
      - id: elements_2
        type: element_2
        repeat-until: _.is_u4
      - id: elements_4
        type: element_4
        repeat: eos
  element_2:
    seq:
      - id: group
        type: u2
      - id: data
        type: u2
    instances:
      is_u4:
        value: group == 2 and data == 0x0101
  element_4:
    seq:
      - id: group
        type: u2
      - id: data
        type: u4
```

Please tell me if I got it right and that will work for your project?

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising! For some reason I was searching for a way to repeat until the first non-2-group entry, but that not helped. Let me first apply this to my real world scenario before I accept your answer.

Comment: I had to find out this does not work if is_u4 is never set, as the end of stream is hit and an exception is generated. Is there a `repeat: until or eos` option or something similar?

Comment: Try `repeat-until: _.is_u4 or _io.eof`